# Having some problems with creating special type objects for groovy

Tags: groovy, syntax, type-conversion

When you start to use gpath processing for collections in groovy, exactly what type of data structure you are dealing with can get somewhat confusing (at least for me)--typically in groovy you just use "Duck typing" and everything works, but Duck Typing actually harms the coders understanding of what a variable might contain at any point in time.

In order to keep it straight I started breaking out variables as types to improve understanding.  The types however are very cryptic and unhelpful:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>
```

is actually a pretty common (and immensely useful) intermediate structure, but someone looking at that in code isn't really helped.  (It acts much like an indexed/grouped sql table if it's not obvious, which I bet it's not)

While explaining my code to a co-worker (and trying to understand it myself) I created a few new types that more clearly state my intentions:

```
class Row extends LinkedHashMap<String, String>{}    // Record--like a row in a table
class Table extends ArrayList<Row>{}                 // A table--like an SQL table.  A list of rows    
class GroupedTable extends LinkedHashMap<String, Table> // A map of tables indexed by some name using groupBy()
```

This works surprisingly well.  After defining these I could say things like:

```
Table t=sql.rows(someQuery) as Table
Row r=t.get(0)
GroupedTable grouped= t.groupBy{it.an_sql_column} as GroupedTable
```

Sometimes I don't have to manually coerce the values (as in the Row) sometimes I do (as in the GroupedTable) which is a little confusing but it generally works (even with @TypeChecked turned on)

The biggest confusion I'm having is that even though grouped was "Converted" to GroupedTable, this closure signature doesn't work:

```
grouped.collect{String modelName, Table subTable->…}
```

It will break at runtime because even though I converted the grouped object using "as GroupedTable", it didn't convert the values returned from groupBy from LinkedLists to a tables.

It works if I use the closure signature:

```
grouped.collect{String modelName, LinkedList subTable->…}
```

but everywhere else things seem to automatically convert nicely. I tried to specify ", subTable as Table" but that is not valid syntax for a closure.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to either supply an "Automatic" conversion from LinkedList to table or to easily process a GroupedTable so that it contains Tables for it's values instead of LinkedLists

A small set of automatic conversions that made Row, Table and GroupedTable work more smoothly would be my ideal solution, but I don't think that asType() is going to do it since I'd need to apply that to LinkedList instead of Table (and it would probably require explicit "as" conversion anyway.)

Update--I just made a "fix" method in GroupedTable that seems to fix the problem but is clunky!

```
def fix(){keyset().each{put(it, get(it) as Table)}}
```

Comment: `this closure signature doesn't work` - why? any error?

Comment: It's a type exception at runtime.  The real type inside the GroupedTable is LinkedList even though the generics are for a Table.  This exception seems right since generics information is erased after I coerce the result of the .groupBy() into a GroupedTable--it's contents aren't converted from LinkedList to Table.  Many other places seem to automatically convert the types though--it's just that this one place doesn't.

Comment: implement groupBy method that will return types you need.

Comment: That would work too, but would change the closure flow quite a bit unless I retrofitted List. I was kind of hoping to find something like asType() but worked in reverse without being explicitly called.  like "GroupedTable.fromType(LinkedList)"

Comment: @daggett I'm probably going to do that--implement a groupBy in Table.  If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: By using coercion ("as Type") you are actually creating new objects and not always in the way you might think.  This is not like a `typedef` in C where you are referring to something by a different name.  If `sql.getRecords(query)` returns "List<Map<String, Strinig>>", that's what I'd use as the variable type.  It would help to know the type of `sql` variable in your example.

Comment: SQL is a groovy class (groovy.lang.SQL I think).  The return type is List<Map<String, String(or Object?)>>.  @Emilles why do you feel there is a problem with converting the objects?  It's working pretty well.  There is certainly some CPU/memory wasted but since I'm not failing any speed requirements, coding in a less clear way in trade for speed would certainly fall under the "Premature Optimization" umbrella.  I can even add new methods to these classes for table-like manipulations (I already have a stand-alone ascii pretty-print method for a table structure I might stick in there)

Comment: @Daggett No point in me accepting my own answer, but if  you post a minimal answer (Just what you said in the comment) I'll edit in the code I've generated to do what you suggested and accept it.

Comment: @BillK If you could edit your original post to make the types more clear, it would be easier to give examples of alternatives.  `groovy.sql.Sql` does not have a `getRecords` method, so I can only make speculative suggestions based on partial information.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "rows", not getRecords.  Rows returns a List<GroovyRowResult> which is essentially a List<Map>.  Hmm, instead of defining my own Row I should probably just use GroovyRowResult as a type.  I never use it because with Groovy you usually just use "def" and forget about the data types altogether (which is what I'm trying to fix in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why auto-type conversion does not work

however, you could `@Override` the `groupBy`method like this:

(Edit by billk--this is how I implemented Daggett's suggestion)

```
class Table extends ArrayList<Row> {
    GroupedTable groupBy(Closure closure)
    def gt=DefaultGroovyMethods.groupBy(this as Iterable, closure) as GroupedTable
    gt.changeTypeOfAllValuesToTable()
    return gt

    static Table build(Iterable list){
        return list.collect{it as Row} as Table
    }
}

class GroupedTable extends LinkedHashMap<String, Table> {
    GroupedTable changeTypeOfAllValuesToTable()
    this.keySet().each{String k->
        Table t=Table.build(get(k))
        put(k, t)
        return this
}
```

With a little extra effort (I could post it if anyone is interested) I got these all to work with the @TypeChecked annotation.  I will probably clean these up and make more useful classes out of them.